# access to folder jenkins workspace for nginx, ubuntu 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, jenkins

I have a folder web that jenkins manages:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myweb
```

*jenkins user is the owner

and from nginx I set up the default site with:

```
   root /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myweb/build;
```

before when the site was in /var/www/html was working well, the owner

not now, how I can set up the rights for the web folder to www-data ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chown` command this way

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myweb
```